# How to stretch a sprite mask programatically across the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a sprite mask cover the bottom 90% of my screen, so that my UI which sits on the top 10% can be clearly seen. To do this I am using Unity's SpriteMask script. The problem I am getting is that the only way that I can scale the SpriteMask is by changing its LocalScale, and I am unsure of the calculation required to convert my screen size to the local scale required for this mask.

I tried using the pixels per unit value but I cant seem to figure out how to relate this to the pixel value of the actual mask's size on screen. When comparing the bounds of the sprite to the various screen width values I can calculate I am struggling to find any relation that would let me calculate them.

My current scaling script is as follows (and doesn't work)

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SpriteMaskScreenSizer : ScreenSizer
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteMask _mask;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _scaleFactor = Vector2.one;

    protected override void UpdateSize()
    {
        if (_mask == null)
        {
            _mask = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteMask>();
        }

        float ppu = _mask.sprite.pixelsPerUnit;
        Vector3 newScale = transform.localScale;
        float desiredWidth, xScale, desiredHeight, yScale;
        switch (_stretchDirection)
        {
            case StretchDirection.Horizontal:
                // Grab the width
                desiredWidth = ScreenSize.x;
                xScale = desiredWidth / ppu;
                newScale.x = xScale * _scaleFactor.x;
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Vertical:
                // Grab the height
                desiredHeight = ScreenSize.y;
                yScale = desiredHeight / ppu;
                newScale.y = yScale * _scaleFactor.y;
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Both:
            {
                // Grab the width
                desiredWidth = ScreenSize.x;
                xScale = desiredWidth / ppu;
                newScale.x = xScale * _scaleFactor.x;
                // Grab the height
                desiredHeight = ScreenSize.y;
                yScale = desiredHeight / ppu;
                newScale.y = yScale * _scaleFactor.y;
                break;
            }
            case StretchDirection.None:
            default:
                // Do nothing.
                break;
        }
        transform.localScale = newScale;
    }
}
```

The ScreenSizer is a base class that just handles calling update or registering with my resolution change watcher as I have a number of different screen sizers for various types of objects.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenSizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected enum StretchDirection
    {
        Horizontal,
        Vertical,
        Both,
        Custom,
        None
    }

    [SerializeField] protected StretchDirection _stretchDirection = StretchDirection.None;
    [SerializeField] private bool _shouldRegisterForResolutionChange = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool _shouldRunOnUpdate = false;

    public void Awake()
    {
        if (_shouldRegisterForResolutionChange)
        {
            BaseGame.Instance.ResolutionService.RegisterAction(OnResolutionChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (_shouldRunOnUpdate || (!Application.isPlaying && _shouldRegisterForResolutionChange))
        {
            UpdateSize();
        }
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (_shouldRegisterForResolutionChange)
        {
            BaseGame.Instance.ResolutionService.DeregisterAction(OnResolutionChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnResolutionChanged(Vector2 resolution)
    {
        UpdateSize();
    }

    protected Vector2 ScreenSize
    {
        get
        {
            Vector2 result = Vector2.zero;
            Vector3 topRight = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.one);
            Vector3 bottomLeft = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero);
            result.x = topRight.x - bottomLeft.x;
            result.y = topRight.y - bottomLeft.y;
            return result;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateSize()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException("Must implement UpdateSize for any screen sizer.");
    }
}
```

I created some info scripts just to visualize in the editor the screen size (two different calculations):

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ScreenSizeInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _screenSize = Vector2.zero;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _cameraScreenSize = Vector2.zero;

    public void Update()
    {
        _screenSize.x = Screen.width;
        _screenSize.y = Screen.height;

        Vector3 topRight = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.one);
        Vector3 bottomLeft = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero);
        _cameraScreenSize.x = topRight.x - bottomLeft.x;
        _cameraScreenSize.y = topRight.y - bottomLeft.y;
    }
}
```

And the extents of the sprite mask (and also of the sprite just to check any relationships):

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SpriteMaskInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteMask _mask;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _spriteBounds;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _spriteExtents;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _maskBounds;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _maskExtents;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (_mask == null)
        {
            _mask = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteMask>();
            return;
        }
        _maskBounds = _mask.bounds.size;
        _spriteBounds = _mask.sprite.bounds.size;
        _maskExtents = _mask.bounds.extents;
        _spriteExtents = _mask.sprite.bounds.extents;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of my editor with my various scripts on the masking object:

[image: SpriteMash Inspector]

[image: Camera Inspector]

I would really appreciate any help on what the calculation I need to use to connect these various values if anyone has run into this similar problem.

Comment: pardon me but why do you need a script for a quadrilateral shaped mask ? also RectMask'ish components can mask a sprites and if i dont misunderstand your words this is the thing is yours exactly need.

Comment: Looking at RectMask, it is part of the Canvas system. I am not using the canvas to render my game scene objects because some of them are mesh renderers (I need to deform the their mesh for some of my mechanics)

And I need a script to scale the object so that it resizes to match the screen size no matter what the device resolution is.

Comment: there have a reason why i said 'ish' word :) As u known you have to derive depends of your hierarchy, world space & camera interaction. I wish to help you but i dont see any informable hierarchy view at your explaniation image and its limits related factors. As always every thinkable problem has a different way to solved.. Best of luck.

Comment: @BerkAskin I added screenshots of my hierarchy, the mask is just a child sitting at 0,0.0 in the scene, all parents are scaled 1,1,1 and at the origin

Comment: @MickyD I updated with the ScreenSizer class.

Comment: _"I updated with the ScreenSizer class"_ - thank-you

Comment: BTW, Unity `MonoBehaviour` methods `Awake`, `Start`, `Update` et al should be marked `private` **not** `public`.

Comment: Consider making `ScreenSizer` an `abstract class` and change `protected virtual void UpdateSize() { throw ... }` to `protected abstract void UpdateSize();`.  This ensures the method is implemented in derived types and removes the need for a runtime check.

Comment: @MickyD `Unity MonoBehaviour methods Awake, Start, Update et al should be marked private` .. doesn't really matter at all though ;)

Comment: @derHugo true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work but it's not the generalized solution I wanted. I just manually set the size to be correct and then recorded both that size and the target resolution it was at when I designed it. Then when the resolution changes I rescale it to the new resolution. I'm sure there has to be a way to relate the scale of the object to the screen resolution somehow and do it without any manual setup, but I cannot figure out what that is, so here is something that works:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SpriteMaskScreenSizer : ScreenSizer
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteMask _mask;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _scaleFactor = Vector2.one;
    // The resolution the sprite was designed for
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _designedResolution = new Vector2(1024f, 768f);
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _designedSize = Vector2.one;

    protected override void UpdateSize()
    {
        if (_mask == null)
        {
            _mask = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteMask>();
        }

        Vector3 newScale = transform.localScale;
        float desiredWidth, xScale, desiredHeight, yScale;
        switch (_stretchDirection)
        {
            case StretchDirection.Horizontal:
                // Grab the width
                desiredWidth = ScreenSize.x;
                xScale = desiredWidth * (_designedSize.x / _designedResolution.x);
                newScale.x = xScale * _scaleFactor.x;
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Vertical:
                // Grab the height
                desiredHeight = ScreenSize.y;
                yScale = desiredHeight * (_designedSize.y / _designedResolution.y);
                newScale.y = yScale * _scaleFactor.y;
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Both:
            {
                // Grab the width
                desiredWidth = ScreenSize.x;
                xScale = desiredWidth * (_designedSize.x / _designedResolution.x);
                newScale.x = xScale * _scaleFactor.x;
                // Grab the height
                desiredHeight = ScreenSize.y;
                yScale = desiredHeight * (_designedSize.y / _designedResolution.y);
                newScale.y = yScale * _scaleFactor.y;
                break;
            }
            case StretchDirection.None:
            default:
                // Do nothing.
                break;
        }
        transform.localScale = newScale;
    }

    public void SetDesignedResolution()
    {
        _designedResolution = ScreenSize;
        _designedSize = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y);
    }
}
```

## UPDATE

I figured it out while resizing my other sprite classes for when not in tiled/sliced mode, which required a similar calculation. This will resize the scale of the SpriteMask to match your screen width/height no matter what sprite you pixelsperunit you are using.

```
public class SpriteMaskScreenSizer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteMask _mask;
    void Update()
    {
        float screenWidth = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector2.zero).x - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector2.one).x);
        float screenHeight = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector2.zero).y - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector2.one).y);     
        float w = _mask.sprite.bounds.size.x;
        float h = _mask.sprite.bounds.size.y;
        float adjustedWidthScale = screenWidth / w;
        float adjustedHeightScale = screenHeight / h;
        switch (_stretchDirection)
        {
            case StretchDirection.Horizontal:
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(adjustedWidthScale, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Vertical:
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, adjustedHeightScale, transform.localScale.z);
                break;
            case StretchDirection.Both:
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(adjustedWidthScale, adjustedHeightScale, transform.localScale.z);
                break;
            case StretchDirection.None:
            default:
                // do nothing if we haven't selected a stretch direction
                return;
    }
}
```